# Selenium mobile browser testing factors besides user agent switching

Tags: python, google-chrome, selenium

[image]

I'd like to test multiple mobile user agents with selenium and chrome. I've found that when I use the chrome extension 'User-Agent Switcher for Google Chrome' ( see info in screenshot above )most websites will accept chrome as the mobile version. However if I use selenium :

```
ua = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 7.0; LG-TP260 Build/NRD90U; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/66.0.3359.126 Mobile Safari/537.36'

options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
ua_string = 'user-agent=' + ua
options.add_argument(ua_string)
webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options=options)
```

The behavior is different and its not always Identified as a mobile chrome. Are there other factors besides user agent that need to be set?

Comment: If I understood correctly, you aren't able to simulate mobile behaviour on chrome with selenium. Why can't you use `EnableMobileEmulation` option, which is available to use in selenium / chromedriver.  (C#) `options.EnableMobileEmulation(deviceName);                
            driver = new ChromeDriver(options); `

Comment: Above will launch chrome in Mobile emulation mode with given deivce name. You can have your own custom device setting where you can set resolution, useragent etc.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know about that. Would you like to enter that as an answer ?

Comment: https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/mobile-emulation , http://www.abodeqa.com/mobile-emulation-in-google-chrome-using-selenium-webdriver/ , https://gist.github.com/devinmancuso/ec8ae08fa73402e45bf1

Comment: Have put my comment as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you aren't able to simulate mobile behaviour on chrome with selenium.

You can use EnableMobileEmulation option, which is available to use in selenium / chromedriver. (C#)

```
options.EnableMobileEmulation(deviceName); 
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
```

This code will launch chrome in Mobile emulation mode with given device name. You can have your own custom device setting where you can set resolution, user agent etc.

Comment: How can we invoke the desktop view in mobile automation?